# How to find non-ascii character in a file that Python as found?

Tags: python

I run this code on a file content:

```
try:
    file_content.encode().decode('ascii')
except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
    print(str(e))
```

And it shows me this error message:

> 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 4568: ordinal not in range(128)

It's not useful at all. First of all, it does not tell me line number and column number. It tells me the position, which I have no idea how can I find in VS Code editor.

Then it tells me that `byte 0xe2` is there. I searched and it seems that `0xe2` [is](https://unicodelookup.com/#0xe2/1) **â**. However, when I search that character, I don't have it in my file.

I'm stuck.

How can I find the errors that Python has found using `.decode('ascii')`?

Comment: just do `file_content.decode('utf8').encode('utf-8')`

Comment: If the file is actually in UTF-8 encoding then `0xe2` is the first byte of a UTF-8 multi-byte encoding for some other character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to get `ord` of character and see which one of them lie outside of `ascii range`

see [ascii table](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Epattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html) for more info

```
file = 'soimefile'
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line_number, line in enuemrate(lines, 1):
        for character_position, character in enumerate(line, 1):
            if not (0<= ord(character) <=127):
                print(f"Non ascii character is at line {line_number} at position {character_position} is {character}")
```

way two, using `str.isascii` instead of checking the ord of character

```
file = 'soimefile'
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line_number, line in enuemrate(lines, 1):
        for character_position, character in enumerate(line, 1):
            if not character.isascii():
                print(f"Non ascii character is at line {line_number} at position {character_position} is {character}")
```